# How to remove odd lines from a data chunk

Tags: python

I am trying to append a file in chunks inside a for loop that looks like file1. Is it possible to remove the extra headers and commas from it as shown below, `file2`?

file1

```
[                     temp sw sw_12
 2020-03-03 01:00:00  -0.442021     0               0,
                      temp sw sw_12
 2020-03-03 02:00:00  -0.454708     0               0,
                      temp sw sw_12
 2020-03-03 03:00:00  -0.420297     0               0,
                      temp sw sw_12
 2020-03-03 04:00:00  -0.439903     0               0
]
```

file2

```
                     temp sw sw_12
2020-03-03 01:00:00  -0.442021     0               0
2020-03-03 02:00:00  -0.454708     0               0
2020-03-03 03:00:00  -0.420297     0               0
2020-03-03 04:00:00  -0.439903     0               0
```

sample code

```
file1 = []
window_size = 10

for i in range(window_size, len(datax)):
    data_train_w = datax[i:i+1]
    data_train_w += 0.1
    standardizer = StandardScaler().fit(data_train_w.values)
    data_train_scaled = standardizer.transform(data_train_w.values)
    file1.append(data_train_scaled)
```

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: I will add the code. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Your code doesn't write to a file. It just creates a list named `file1`.

Comment: Yes, I actually don't want to write it to a file but append them to file as shown in the file2 format.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use a list comprehension with `enumerate()`:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as r:
    lines = [ln.rstrip(',') for i,ln in enumerate(r) if i%2 or not i]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```